# Can't find "PAD.Console.Host.exe" on my PC to run flows through PowerShell

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I want to run flows directly through PowerShell and I'm using the following article where they describe how to run flows with URLs:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Power Automate Desktop\PAD.Console.Host.exe" "ms-powerautomate:/console/flow/run?workflowName=[workflowName]"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/run-desktop-flows-url-shortcuts

The problem is that I can't seem to find the exe file PAD.Console.Host.exe anywhere on my PC. Has a recent update changed it to something else and the article is outdated?

I am using Power Automate Desktop and I do not have the premium version.

Answer (score 0):

The file should be available in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Power Automate Desktop" s I can see PAD.Console.Host.exe in the mentioned folder.
Other way of making sure you are checking in the right directory is to go in Services.msc and check the path of any service starting with name "Power Automate.." and searching it there.
If none of this work, suggest reinstalling PAD.